# How to make password match confirmation in jetpack compose?

Tags: validation, android-jetpack-compose

How can I make a password match (confirm password) field validation using Jetpack Compose? I have two fields "password" and "confirm_password".

```
@Composable
fun PasswordTextFieldComponent(
    labelValue: String, painterResource: Painter,
    onTextSelected: (String) -> Unit,
    errorStatus: Boolean = false
) {

    val localFocusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val password = remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    val passwordVisible = remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    OutlinedTextField(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clip(componentShapes.small),
        label = { Text(text = labelValue) },
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
            focusedBorderColor = Primary,
            focusedLabelColor = Primary,
            cursorColor = Primary,
            backgroundColor = BgColor
        ),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password,
            imeAction = ImeAction.Done
        ),
        singleLine = true,
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions {
            localFocusManager.clearFocus()
        },
        maxLines = 1,
        value = password.value,
        onValueChange = {
            password.value = it
            onTextSelected(it)
        },
        leadingIcon = {
            Icon(painter = painterResource, contentDescription = "")
        },
        trailingIcon = {

            val iconImage = if (passwordVisible.value) {
                Icons.Filled.Visibility
            } else {
                Icons.Filled.VisibilityOff
            }

            val description = if (passwordVisible.value) {
                stringResource(id = R.string.hide_password)
            } else {
                stringResource(id = R.string.show_password)
            }

            IconButton(onClick = { passwordVisible.value = !passwordVisible.value }) {
                Icon(imageVector = iconImage, contentDescription = description)
            }

        },
        visualTransformation = if (passwordVisible.value) VisualTransformation.None else PasswordVisualTransformation(),
        isError = !errorStatus
    )
}

@Composable
fun ConfirmPasswordTextFieldComponent(
    text: String,
    confirmText: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    semanticContentDescription: String = "",
    labelText: String = "",
    hasError: Boolean = false,
    onTextChanged: (text: String) -> Unit,
) {
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val showPassword = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val matchError = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
    ) {
        OutlinedTextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .semantics { contentDescription = semanticContentDescription },
            value = text,
            onValueChange = onTextChanged,
            placeholder = {
                Text(
                    text = labelText,
                    color = Color.White,
                    fontSize = 16.sp,

                )
            },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                autoCorrect = true,
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Done
            ),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                onDone = {
                    focusManager.clearFocus()
                }
            ),
            singleLine = true,
            isError = hasError || matchError.value,
            visualTransformation =
            if (showPassword.value) VisualTransformation.None else PasswordVisualTransformation(),
            trailingIcon = {
                val (icon, iconColor) = if (showPassword.value) {
                    Pair(
                        Icons.Filled.Visibility,
                        colorResource(id = R.color.colorBrightViolet200)
                    )
                } else {
                    Pair(Icons.Filled.VisibilityOff, colorResource(id = R.color.colorWhite))
                }

                IconButton(onClick = { showPassword.value = !showPassword.value }) {
                    Icon(
                        icon,
                        contentDescription = "Visibility",
                        tint = iconColor
                    )
                }
            },
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
                focusedBorderColor = Color.White,
                unfocusedBorderColor = Color.White,
                textColor = Color.White,
                cursorColor = Color.White,
            )
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
        if (confirmText != text) {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.error_password_no_match),
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.colorSoftRed300),
                fontSize = 10.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                modifier = Modifier.semantics { contentDescription = "ConfirmPasswordMessage" },
            )
            matchError.value = true
        } else {
            matchError.value = false
        }
    }
}
```